# Getting error "This site can't be reached" for many sites after running docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, ubuntu, automation, docker-compose, dockerfile

Issue: Whenever I run a docker-compose.yml file with command “docker-compose up”, few websites like github and stackoverflow keeps on loading and after few minutes throws an error “This site can’t be reached”/”ERR_TIMED_OUT”, while websites like google and youtube works fine. Below is the docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx: 
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginxContainer
  alpine1:
    image: alpine
    entrypoint: "ping nginx"   
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  alpine2:
    image: alpine
    working_dir: /a/b/c
    entrypoint: "wget nginx"   
    volumes:
      - /home/ramit/Downloads:/a/b/c
    depends_on:
      - nginx
```

When I run the same images via terminal using docker run image command, all websites work fine. The issue is only when I run docker-compose file. I am using latest version of docker and docker-compose.

OS – Ubuntu- 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

This issue exist is both browsers i.e. chrome and firefox. Have tried incognito mode as well, didn’t worked.

Screenshot Links:

https://ibb.co/82ZRSWR -- Chrome Browser

https://ibb.co/h2LtcWJ – Logs of docker-compose up

https://ibb.co/0synCv8 – Firefox Browser

As a part of solution of above issue, I have tried restarting the docker service, making docker-compose down, nothing works. It only starts working whenever I restart my system.

I found the same issue mentioned here as well: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3633

The solution given in this is to remove tty:true from docker-compose.yml file, but I never used that in my file. I have even tried adding tty:false in my docker-compose.yml file, but doesn’t worked.

Would be really great if anyone can help me through it.

Many Thanks

Comment: When do you curl these sites (github and stackoverflow) via terminal, what happened? Example: `curl https://github.com`. Also with the mtr command is possible to see the route of the packages until the final address. Example: `mtr github.com`. Watch the behavior of these two commands to see where exactly the connection is broken.

Comment: Try: 1. Update the version from "3" to "3.8", 2. try to add `networks:   - mynet` to all services and on bottom of the script [see here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network) 3. Try to remove the volume mapping from _alpine2_ 4. change the `ping` entrypoint of the service with `sleep(100000)` 5. try to run the compose as `docker-compose up --no-color`

Comment: Hey @DanielMarques.. have tried running the both commands. Here are the screenshots for both. There is definitely some issue, I am not sure about the solution. https://ibb.co/2tCm34C
https://ibb.co/CBgJ3YY

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know the right answer, but the standout for me is the volume link to downloads on your local machine. Both browsers will use that and perhaps your volume mapping is causing issues.

Comment: Hi.. I have even tried by changing host directory from downloads to home, didn't got any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I am not if your docker file is causing this error, but I have faced similar problem few minutes ago.

From the morning, as soon I started using my laptop I connected it to my mobile hotspot. The internet connection was stable, but I wasn't able to access github, wikipedia and some common websites.

I tried opening the same sites on my mobile, but it was the same **This site can't be reached** then I knew it has something to do with my network, my laptop is guilty free

I simply **turn on and off airplane mode from my mobile** and boom, it worked.

Now I literally have no idea why it worked, but possibly my network provider has provided me ip address which was banned for these websites, because I knew I haven't done anything suspicious, not that I am aware of.

*Sometimes solution is simple*